# Работа с большим количеством текста. Книга

Tags: android

Приложение - книга с главами, большое количество текста.

Подскажите, как лучше, в каком виде хранить текст ? в SQLite ?

Как вообще лучше/грамотнее делать такие приложение с большим количеством текста ?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/194714/ вот тебе краткий набор статей о проектировании БД. ссылки на предыдущие части в верху увидишь.

Comment: спасибо, за статьи. но мой вопрос "как в андроиде гармотно сделать приложение с большом кол-вом текста".